# I really need help learning how to show sequences converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My first problem on this analysis homework (should be the easiest) is

Show that the sequence ${x_n} = \large\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges.

When stuff like the ratio test, etc fail.. I don't know how to do this. Of course, I know the definition of a convergent sequence, but I always get lost in trying to figure out where to start, where to go, what tricks to use...

I would really appreciate it if you guys who are masters at this could guide me through your entire throught process and help me learn how to become a master at showing sequences converge.

Comment: Try Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: condensation? what is that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: Try showing It's value is $\frac{{\pi}^2}{6}$ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${x_n} = \large\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}$ is monotone increasing and ${x_n} = \large\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2} \le 1+ \sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)} \le 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^n(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k})\le2 - \frac{1}{n}\le 2$ ,hence bounded.Therefore, $x_n$ converges.

Comment: i see that now, but how do you start to do that? how do you know where to start and just immediately what to do, that is hard.

Comment: can you tell me a little bit more precisely what it is that you feel ,that I need to elaborate in my proof ?

Comment: @user129017 there's nothing wrong with your proof, I am just asking you personally how you come up with the logic for proving a sequence converges: how do you know where to start and what to look for?

Comment: Ok .. the most standard way of treating convergence of series with positive terms is to show that it is bounded, so to show convergence of $\sum x_n$ where $x_n \ge 0$, one might want to find a series $\sum y_n$ (which is previously known to be a convergent series) such that $y_n \ge x_n$. This is called comparison test of convergence of series. Does that help ? :)

Comment: @terribleatmath Most of the ideas we use are methods already seen and used in our studies and a good mathematician is one who knows how use these ideas in the right place.

Comment: @terribleatmath it is a bit rare that one can just immediately compare a series with a telescopic series. This case is pretty famous and perhaps it is the archetype!

Comment: thanks guys. i think it makes it a bit harder that my sequence here is actually just a partial sum of an infinite series so i have some different ideas. (like trying to use the ratio test)

Comment: just to clarify: does the ratio test apply ONLY to infinite series?